# Rails HTTP Basic check for authenticated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, basic-authentication

I've been googling  this one and haven't turned up anything useful:

Assuming you use http basic auth in Rails is there a simple method to check if the user is authenticated? Ie. a way you can do something like this in a view:

```
- if http_basic_authenticated?
  # show admin menu
```

Comment: Have you tried http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication?

Comment: Yes. That doesn't give any insight into letting the view detect whether a user is auth'd or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a session parameter accessible through a method defined in your `ApplicationController`.

```
class ApplicationController < BaseController

...

  def authorize
    session[:authorized] = true
  end

  def http_basic_authenticated?
    session[:authorized]
  end

  def end_session
    session[:authorized] = nil
  end

end
```

P.S. I'm not a security expert, so I can't comment on the suitability of using this in a production environment.

Comment: With SSL session hijacking shouldn't be a concern and that's the only way I can think of that this would be compromised. So, should be ok for something as simple as what I'm working on. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
class ApplicationController < ..

  before_filter :authenticate

  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      @authenticated = username == "foo" && password == "bar"
    end
  end

  def authenticated?
    @authenticated
  end
  helper_method :authenticated?

end
```

You can now use `authenticated` in your view.

Please write tests!

Answer (score 1):

From the [oficial code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/25b14b4d3238d5474c60826ee1b359537af987ef/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb#L70) you can extract snipets to use something like this in any controller inherited by ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < BaseController
  ...
  protected # Only inherited controllers can call authorized?
  def authorized?
    request.authorization.present? && (request.authorization.split(' ', 2).first == 'Basic')
  end
...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

well, as I could know, there's no way to tell a view that the request is **not authenticated**, you could just tell the view that it is **authenticated**, but why?
let's see the process of a request:

1. Client Request
2. Controller
3. View

and in the 2nd step, the particular controller's method, which is **before-filtered** by the authentication method, that is, if you can go to the 3rd step -- the view, the request must be **authenticated**.